# how to Save the State of an c# App with powerShell?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, powershell, listbox

I have a C# program in which the user adds multiple objects an editing Panel. These objects are all represented as a classes. Now I want the user to be able to save the scenario, so it can be loaded again.

for that I want to generate a Powershell script of each scénario , but my probléme is how to save diferent objects on Powershell , i tried to use serialization with XMLSerializer but I fail ,because i use a lot of dependant object who has Dictionaries and ListBoxs .

Is there some genereic save method I can use?
Can you help me?

Comment: Why do you want to user PowerShell? And how?

Comment: Please clarify - your description is vague and incomplete.

Comment: ok , I want to use powershell for 2 reasons :

Comment: first reason : I want to store my modifications in my application , and the second reason are the capacity to use my application directly with powershell command ,without GUI;

Comment: to do this I cant use Serialisation or object databases , because I want to have all my saved files independant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I stored on a PowerShell Script at each time the right properties of the GUI object. When I want to load my stored object, I replay the last sequence directly on PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell has its own object serializer in the cmdlets **Export-Clixml** and **Import-Clixml**.

`Get-Help Export-Clixml -Full | more` for details...